# Data Breakpoints in VS 2019, .NET 5.0.402, C# (same for VS 2022, .NET 6.0)

Tags: c#, breakpoints

I cannot set the Data Breakpoint in .NET 5 WPF project on C#. I use MVVM and I try to check where in VM some property value is changed.

In Watch window when I select a property which already has some value and in context menu (right-mouse-click) try to select "Break When Value Changes" I get always error "Unable to set data breakpoint. The value cannot be found on the managed heap and cannot be tracked".

It is not possible also to set Data Breakpoint by usong the Visual Studio main menu Debug -> New Breakpoint -> Data Breakpoint because this item is disabled (gray).

Any help or better a working sample will be approciated.